# Seeking open source software or python packages to create orthomosaic and DEM image from UAV images

Tags: openstreetmap, remote-sensing, software-recommendations, aerial-photography

I would like to analyse UAV 2D images to create 3D point cloud, DES, and orthomosaic image.

Can you suggest or mention some open source software or python packages?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Your question needs more focus because it is likely to attract a list of candidates which voting turns into a poll.  Such open-ended questions are welcome in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).  There is also a [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange designed for questions like these.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [OpenDroneMap](https://www.opendronemap.org).

> **Drone Mapping Software**
>
> Generate maps, point clouds, 3D models and DEMs from drone, balloon or kite images.
>
> **Open Source Toolkit for Processing Aerial Imagery**
>
> ODM turns simple
> point-and-shoot camera images into two and three dimensional
> geographic data that can be used in combination with other geographic
> datasets.
>
> In a nutshell, it’s a program that takes images as input and produces
> a variety of georeferenced assets as output, such as maps and 3D
> models.